# Difference between name(path) and path/name() when the output is not a sequence

Tags: xml, xquery, xpath-2.0

Difference between Xquery´s

```
    name(/Data/element1/element2[@ID=$ID]),
```

and

```
    /Data/element1/element2[@ID=$ID]/name()
```

Which is the best-practice when the result IS NOT a sequence? (If it is, then the former one cannnot be used basically)

Anything I forget or are they totally swapable in that circumstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In XPath 2.0 this expression raises an error if the argument to the `name()` function is a sequence with more than one items**:

```
name(/Data/element1/element2)
```

**In XPath 1.0 this isn't an error** and `name()` uses as its argument the first node in the node-set.

Both are equally useless, as it is known at a glance that the result must be `"element2"`.

> Which is the best-practice when the resul IS NOT a sequence (If it is,
>   then the former one cannnot be used basically)?

**This works in both cases in XPath 2.0 / XQuery**:

```
/Data/element1/element2/name()
```

Comment: You are right for the part "the result is known in element2", I changed a bit the example to get the idea. I meant for dynamical selection, maybe I did it too simple

Answer (score 1):

Ok the difference is that there is no difference as it is the same function, because name() equals to name(.), so it is not a different syntax. What it happens is that name(X) should contain ALWAYS an expression with no more than 1 occurrences of output.

so we could use:

```
/Data/name(./element1/element2) = /Data/name(element1/element2) 
 * element2, if a single occurrence in the whole data

/Data/element1/name(./element2) = /Data/element1/name(element2)
 * element2, if a single occurrence per any element1, for each element1

/Data/element1/element2/name() = /Data/element1/element2/name(.)
 * element2, no matter num of occurrences, we print them all
```

So when we expect only one occurrence, name(complete_expression) could be favoured since we can add an extra validation step for our assumption, but the alternative has also the strong point that we can prepare the terrain for handling multiple inputs for the expression (array) if, someday, data changes and that is valid  and expected